# WebDriverIO: waitFor <title> to be X

Tags: webdriver-io

Is there a pattern with the current `2.0` library that would allow me to wait until the current Page's title is X? For the purpose of pausing the WebDriver until I am on the page I wish to be after several redirects?

This would be easy if I could do `driver.waitFor('title:contains("Google")');`

Answer (score 1):

Webdriver 3.0 now has a waitUntil function that you could use to accomplish this. http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitUntil.html

```
driver.waitUntil(function() {
  return this.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    if(title === 'Google') {
       return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get over yourself and your CSS selectors. When in doubt, just use XPATH.

`driver.waitFor('//title[text() = "Google"]');`

Answer (score 0):

With webdriver 3.0+ you can also add a browser [custom command](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/customcommands.html) somewhere in a module shared across all your tests:

```js
browser.addCommand('waitForTitle', function (title, timeout) {
    browser.waitUntil(function () {
        return browser.getTitle() === title;
    }, timeout | 3000);
});
```

Then call it from you test code:

```js
it('should navigate to login page', function () {
    browser.click('.login-button');
    browser.waitForTitle('Login');
});
```